# Displaying product category names in the WordPress order table (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There are orders that have already been completed or not, and they contain goods, clothing, courses, etc. In WordPress, I have all the products subdivided into categories, but I don't know how to display the names of these categories. Suppose I have an order from a T-shirt and some course, and in the category I have to display "Clothes, Courses" (In the picture below, it is marked in red where it is necessary to display). I was able to display only the "Categories" tab, but the categories themselves cannot be displayed at all :( Here is the code from the orders.php file

```html
<table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
                ?>


                <tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_status() ); ?> order">
                    <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number() ); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-cat' === $column_id ) : ?>


                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                /* translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                                echo wp_kses_post( sprintf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ) );
                                ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );

                                if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                                    foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And here is the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xNv4.png)

Comment: Can this help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092967/modify-woocommerce-orders-php-columns

Comment: No: (the above example shows how to simply add columns and rows, but I need to add categories to the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = $order->get_items();

$cats = '';

foreach($items as $key => $item) {

    $product_id    = $item['product_id'];
    $term_obj_list = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');
    $terms_string  = implode(', ', wp_list_pluck($term_obj_list, 'name'));

    $cats .= $terms_string;
}

echo $cats;
```

Put this in correct elseif block of your given code.

Updated according to the comment with code comment:

```
//Getting all the items in the order
$items = $order->get_items();

$c_list = [];

/**
 * Loop through all items and get their categories [a product can have multiple category]
 */
foreach($items as $key => $item) {

    //We need the product id to retrieved the categories
    $product_id    = $item['product_id'];
    
    //Retrieving all the categories that product has
    $term_obj_list = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');
    

    //Loop through all the categories the current product has and saving it in a array with category id as index
    //so that if the save category is assigned to another product we do not get the duplicate category
    foreach($term_obj_list as $term_obj) {
        $c_list[$term_obj->term_id] = $term_obj->name;
    }
}

//lastly we concatenating all the categories with ", "
$cats = implode(', ', $c_list);

//printing the final result
echo $cats;
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Everything works!
I would also like to ask you to tell in a nutshell how this code works, so that I can understand it and not face such a problem again :)
And I would also like to know if you can help with the fact that I have 6 tabs at the top and I need to check: If there are clothes in the order, then display them in the "All orders" tab and in "Clothes" and also with courses etc.

Comment: And the problem is that if the order consists of 2 items of clothing, then in the category I will be displayed not just "Clothes" 2 times "Clothes"